# Pandas groupby on mixed type column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply pandas groupby to a column which contains floats and strings. The DataFrame looks like:

```
     name      value
0    var_1     1.4
1    var_2     1110
3    var_2     900
4    var_3     'some_str'
5    var_1     2.7
```

I am trying to apply the groupby method so that the output dataframe looks something like:

```
     name      value
0    var_1     2.15
1    var_2     1005
2    var_3     'some_str'
```

i.e. the get the average of all those values which are recorded multiple times, and preserve the  no-numeric values as they are.

If the column was only made up of numeric types this would be simple enough to implement as:

```
new_df = df.groupby('name').mean().reset_index()
```

Is there an easy way to overcome the mixed types which makes this method as I have written above inapplicable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try-except` statement:

```
#if need convert strings column to mixed values
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['value'])
```

---

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return x.mean()
    except:
        return ','.join(x)

new_df = df.groupby('name')['value'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (new_df)
    name       value
0  var_1        2.05
1  var_2        1005
2  var_3  'some_str'
```